# How to paginate over Facebook interests fetched through Marketing API?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get access to the full list of interests that Facebook uses for targeting ads. Apparently the API endpoint `/search` should allow me to do this (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-search#interest_browse). However when I call this endpoint I just get 328 results. I have been trying to use pagination as indicated in the documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#paging) but nothing seems to have worked so far. I would assume that if any, this endpoint works with offset-based pagination as the `paging` attribute is not present in the response. However the parameters `limit` and `offset` are ignored when I provide them. Here is the code I'm using:

```
import json
import requests

params={
  'type': 'adTargetingCategory',
  'class': 'interests',
  'limit': 10,
  'offset': 5,
  'access_token': '<ACCESS_TOKEN>'
}

res = requests.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/search', params).json()
```

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Not all endpoints support pagination. And since `limit` does not seem to have any effect on the results here, I would assume this is one that doesn’t.

Comment: @CBroe any idea if it is possible to confirm that this is indeed the case (pagination not supported)? Apparently this was supported in previous versions of the API but they are not accessible anymore.